# SDK Java Api MS Exchange online & server

Tags: api, ms-office, exchangewebservices

I'm trying to integrate my Java third-party application with MS Exchange online and on-premises, I need to access all the users data (mails, calendar, contacts...). I've read about the apps authentication process (OAuth 2 for online and NTLM for on-premises).

Is there a Java SDK compatible with both Exchange online and on-premises and which provides both authentication process?

Because I found this one ( http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Exchange-EWS-Java-API-12-1a5a1143 ) but it seems to only support NTLM authentication and no OAuth2.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to try the JWebServices for Exchange client. It will target Exchange Online and on-premises, and is appears to be up to date according to IndependentSoft's site. This is not an endorsement, I've never used that client. I doubt this client uses OAuth and the new Exchange REST end points.